# some errors into the driver RT539x PCIe

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I have a laptop HP650 with Wi fi chip RT539a. I'm using OS ubuntu
12.04, but the wifi does not work on this OS. The forum ubuntu gave me
a couple of tips on how to solve these issues.
Here they are:

- Download the linux driver (RT5390PCIe) from Ralink.
- Extract it.  The files will be extracted to 2010_1216_RT5390_LinuxSTA_V2.4.0.4_WiFiBTCombo_DPO folder.
- Download all the patches except the x64_86 patch, assuming you have a 32-bit system, from opensuse website.
- Copy the patches to the folder – 2010_1216_RT5390_LinuxSTA_V2.4.0.4_WiFiBTCombo_DPO
      Goto the folder.
- Make the following change in  /os/linux/config.mk file – HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT=y (originally was n)

  `sudo su`
      `cp RT2860STA.dat RT5390STA.dat`
      `mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT5390STA`
      `cp RT5390STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT5390STA`
      `make clean`
      `make   <- i have problems`
      `make install`
      `modprobe rt5390sta`
      `exit`

But at one stage when I run "make", I have a compiler error:

```
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c: In function
‘AsicGetAutoAgcOffsetForTemperatureSensor’:
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:1233:28: warning:
assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
[enabled by default]
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:1246:28: warning:
assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
[enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.c: In function
‘HWAntennaDiversityEnable’:
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.c:2010:2: error: ‘regs’
undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.c:2010:2: note: each
undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it
appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/hp650/rt/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/hp650/rt/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Someone can help me in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll have better luck with a newer version of RT5390: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58267392/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.zip

Comment: @karel I doubt that any file from 2011 will compile on any recent not end-of-life kernel. I will address the new question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I own an HP650 which came with pre-installed SUSE Linux Enterprise Novell.

The wireless card on this laptop is the Ralink 539a. The driver/module for this wlan card loaded by the kernel is the `rt2800pci`. The problem of course is that by default they do not work or if they work its unstable and practically unusable.

After reading many threads and following a lot of different lines to build the 
`2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO` the result was never successful failing either at the build with `make` returning an error for Antenna being changed to y for yes
or the driver not starting the `wlan0` interface if the Antenna switch remains n for off.

Later I found a bug report and exchange specifically for the Ralink 539a where the solution to the problem was finally found:

1. Download latest Compat-Wireless drivers from [linuxwireless.org](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download/stable/#compat-wireless_3.6_stable_releases)
2. Unpack to a directorv
3. `cd` to directory
4. `sudo make`
5. `sudo make install`
6. reboot your computer
7. make sure the wireless card light/led is on by using the wireless on/off button....

That did it for me.

A note I also read is that **any time the kernel or drivers are updated** the old rt2800pci driver/module gets unpacked and thus the wireless gets back to not working. So the same procedure of `make` and `make install` to overwrite with the `compat.wireless` drivers that work is to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this same problem for later Ubuntu versions and kernel version 3.8 and above, I made a simple fix for it a while ago. I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04:

This package contains driver, patch and full instructions for both installation and recompiling the driver after each kernel upgrade.

https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver